# Changing functions to ES6 becomes malfunction

Tags: javascript

```
    const panels = document.querySelectorAll('.panel');

    function toggleOpen() {
      console.log('Hello');
      this.classList.toggle('open');
    }

    function toggleActive(e) {
      console.log(e.propertyName);
      if (e.propertyName.includes('flex')) {
        this.classList.toggle('open-active');
      }
    }

    panels.forEach(panel => panel.addEventListener('click',toggleOpen));
    panels.forEach(panel => panel.addEventListener('transitionend',toggleActive));
```

If I replace the above toggleOpen and toggleActive functions using ES6 as below, the listener becomes malfunction. Can somebody explain the reason and provide  suggestions?

```
    const toggleOpen = (e) =>{
      console.log('Hello');
      e.target.classList.toggle('open');
    }
    const toggleActive = (e) =>{
      console.log(e.propertyName);

      if(e.propertyName.includes('flex')){
        e.target.classList.toggle('open-active');
      }
    }
```

Comment: Malfunction in what way, are there errors in the console, are other things happening that are supposed to, etc?

Comment: suspect `e.target` is not equivalent to `this` used prior because event is being caught during bubble. Need to see the HTML structure of the `.panel` element.

Comment: Sometimes when I click on the .panel , it is not functioning well when I change to  `e.target` instead of `this`

Comment: [link](https://github.com/wesbos/JavaScript30/blob/master/05%20-%20Flex%20Panel%20Gallery/index-FINISHED.html) This is the link for the code